# Function call using $on cannot be from the $scope

Tags: angularjs

I am using a normal $rootScope.$broadcast to transfer control to a different controller. The other controller is trying to call a function based on this. The question is can this function that is being called a $scope function or it has always to be a private function within the controller. So when I write the below:

```
  $scope.$on('aRequest',function(){console.log('it works')});
```

It works as expected. But when I write:

```
 $scope.$on('aRequest',$scope.someFunction());
```

It doesn't work. I don't see a syntax error in the console as well. Am I missing something?

Like to add that when this call is made like below as well it works:

```
 $scope.$on('aRequest',iWorkProperly);
 var iWorkProperly = function(){};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write `$scope.$on('toggleNavRequest',$scope.someFunction);` without the `()` - You're passing the reference to the function, and not actually triggering it (Angular will trigger the function call)

Example:

```
$scope.someFunction = function() {
    console.log("Hi");
};

$scope.$on('toggleNavRequest',$scope.someFunction);
```

Comment: I am getting a someFunction is not defined error. I will try to get a plunkr may be. I tried the way you have suggested and forgot to mention the same as it was throwing an error. Also, if I am just passing the reference does it not throw an error as it should not pass the same.

Comment: Should have wait for grunt to complete the watch tasks. My bad. Thanks Mate.